# Split string after matching the word in shell

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, split

I have a csv file in that values are like:

```
Wt-Do-U-Do-Wit-The-Black,black
Yay-Its-Your-Birthday-Black,black
You-Are-My-Sunshine-Happy-Birthday-Red,red
You-Are-Special-Navy-Blue,navy-blue
You-Dont-Look-A-Day-Over-Fabulous-Green,green
You-My-Friend-Are-Ridiculously-Fabulous-Happy-Birthday-Pink,pink
```

I want to split each string before colour name comes.For Ex:

```
str1=Wt-Do-U-Do-Wit-The   
str1=Yay-Its-Your-Birthday 
str1=You-Are-My-Sunshine-Happy-Birthday
str1=You-Are-Special   
str1=You-Dont-Look-A-Day-Over-Fabulous
str1=You-My-Friend-Are-Fabulous-Happy-Birthday
```

For searching the string i am using :-

```
if  [ "$string" == *"Black"* ] && [ "$string" == *"White"* ] ; then
              echo "It's there!"
else
    echo "SOrry"
fi
```

It is searching fine. But how can I split the string?

Another way I used :

```
colour_arr[0]='Red'
colour_arr[1]='Black'
colour_arr[2]='Navy-Blue'
colour_arr[3]='White'
inarray=$(echo ${colour_arr[@]} | grep -o "$string" | wc -w)
echo "$inarray"
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Can you give your exact input as it is with an expected output rather than posting what you have tried to solve the  problem (unknown) `X-Y problem`

Comment: Does the input lines have following pattern `"4 words",colorname` ?

Comment: @sameerkn :Firts column have different string not  only 4 words,colour name is same

Comment: @Urvashi: You want to store the fields in variables or array? What is that you want to do after parsing the lines?

Comment: @Urvashi It is not very kind changing the input format half an hour after posting the question.

Comment: i want to extract the name til colour comes

Comment: @Urvashi: Why is this line `You-Are-My-Sunshine-Happy-Birthday-Red,red  S` having an extra character `S` after `red`

Comment: If color is always the second and last field of each field, you could simply use `cut -d',' -f1` . Is that the case?

Comment: @Inian typing mistake 'S' after red

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou i want to extract colour from the string.This is my string "You-Are-My-Sunshine-Happy-Birthday-Red" desire output "You-Are-My-Sunshine-Happy-Birthday"

Comment: @Urvashi: Refer my answer below

Comment: OK. If the color is always in the end of the string separated by `-` then you can simply use `a="You-Are-My-Sunshine-Happy-Birthday-Red" ;
awk -F- '{print $NF}' <<<"$a"` or even `awk -F- '{print $NF}' file.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `sed`; inspired from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24151/64031)

I simplified the problem a little since you parsed the strings already correctly; using this input file:

```
This is red colour
Ball is  black colour
some more words before red and more after
```

for the second part of the string; starting with the color name:

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*\(\(red\|black\).*\)/\1/p' test
```

gives:

```
red colour
black colour
red and more after
```

and

```
sed -n -e 's/\(^.*\)\(\(red\|black\).*\)/\1/p' test
```

gives:

```
This is 
Ball is  
some more words before
```

I won't explain all the options; since they are well explained in the answer I referred to. You can use sed on a bash variable using:

```
leftpart=$(sed -n -e 's/\(^.*\)\(\(red\|black\).*\)/\1/p' <<< $INPUT_STRING)
```

**EDIT after the OP changed the input format:**
my answer still applies; just replace red with Red. The rest applies the same.

Comment: Thanks .It works.                                                                                  leftpart=$(sed -n -e 's/\(^.*\)\(\(red\|black\).*\)/\1/p' <<< $INPUT_STRING)

Answer (score 1):

> For your new input

**Input**

```
$ cat f2
Wt-Do-U-Do-Wit-The-Black,black
Yay-Its-Your-Birthday-Black,black
You-Are-My-Sunshine-Happy-Birthday-Red,red  S
You-Are-Special-Navy-Blue,navy-blue
You-Dont-Look-A-Day-Over-Fabulous-Green,green
You-My-Friend-Are-Ridiculously-Fabulous-Happy-Birthday-Pink,pink
```

**Output ( Using `gawk` )**

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;FS="[ ,]";OFS=","}match($1,$2){print "str1="substr($1,1,RSTART-2)}' f2
str1=Wt-Do-U-Do-Wit-The
str1=Yay-Its-Your-Birthday
str1=You-Are-My-Sunshine-Happy-Birthday
str1=You-Are-Special
str1=You-Dont-Look-A-Day-Over-Fabulous
str1=You-My-Friend-Are-Ridiculously-Fabulous-Happy-Birthday
```

> For your old input

**Input**

```
$ cat f
"This is red colour",red
"Ball is  black colour",black
"Tshirt is white colour",white
"Shoes are blue colour",blue
"This is green colour",green
```

**Output**

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{gsub(/"/,"");match($1,$2);print "str1="substr($1,1,RSTART-1),"str2=" substr($1,RSTART) }' f
str1=This is ,str2=red colour
str1=Ball is  ,str2=black colour
str1=Tshirt is ,str2=white colour
str1=Shoes are ,str2=blue colour
str1=This is ,str2=green colour
```

Comment: The output is indeed what the user asks for; but this does not give him each part of the string in a bash variable...

Answer (score 0):

OneLiner using awk (gnu for IGNORECASE)

```
awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}{sub("-"$NF"$","",$1);print "str1="$1}' YourFile
```

Self commented code

```
awk -F ',' '# sepeartor of field is coma
 # before first line
 BEGIN{
    # define case compair behaviour (ignoring  the case)
    IGNORECASE=1
    }
 # for each line
 {
    # substitute the pattern ( minus than field 2 content, so the color, at the end) in fields 1 by "" (remove)
    sub( "-" $NF "$", "", $1)
    # print the new content of filed 1 with str1= before
    print "str1="$1
    }' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you need color out of first "dashed" field , not the value of the second field (comma separated).

If color in this first "dashed" field is always the last string (dash separated), you can simply use
`a="You-Are-My-Sunshine-Happy-Birthday-Red" ; awk -F- '{print $NF}' <<<"$a"`

PS: You can isolate the first field of the whole line with cut or awk:
`awk -f, '{print $1}' <<<"$fileline"` or `cut -d, -f1 <<<"$fileline"`

You can combine above two to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
$< input.txt
Wt-Do-U-Do-Wit-The-Black,black
Yay-Its-Your-Birthday-Black,black
You-Are-My-Sunshine-Happy-Birthday-Red,red
You-Are-Special-Navy-Blue,navy-blue
You-Dont-Look-A-Day-Over-Fabulous-Green,green
You-My-Friend-Are-Ridiculously-Fabulous-Happy-Birthday-Pink,pink

$sed  -E 's/(-[^-]+)(,.*)/\2/g' input.txt
Wt-Do-U-Do-Wit-The,black
Yay-Its-Your-Birthday,black
You-Are-My-Sunshine-Happy-Birthday,red
You-Are-Special-Navy,navy-blue
You-Dont-Look-A-Day-Over-Fabulous,green
You-My-Friend-Are-Ridiculously-Fabulous-Happy-Birthday,pink
```

(Note: on my OS, OSX, sed -E is for extended regex.)